# Getting data from Realtime Database with a conditional statement

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

how I can show DeliveryBoys in a specific location, in my realtime database I have a value that I need to compare drivers with which is "City" I would like to have all DeliveryBoys that are in a specific city. How can I do that? Using flutter

Am only able to get all drivers without a conditional statement

**This is my Function that i want to modify **

```
 retrieveOnlineDriversInformation(List onlineNearestDriversList) async {
    DatabaseReference ref =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("DeliveryBoys");
    for (int i = 0; i < onlineNearestDriversList.length; i++) {
      await ref
          .child(onlineNearestDriversList[i].driverId.toString())
          .once()
          .then((dataSnapshot) {
        var driverKeyInfo = dataSnapshot.snapshot.value;
        dList.add(driverKeyInfo);
      });
    }
  }
```

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y6U1.png)

Comment: you can not query the real-time database. you have to filter online users on the result locally.

Comment: @Manish Dayma How can i do that from the sample code provided am stuck?

Comment: Can you show a view of your database structure.

Comment: @GrahamD updated please click on Database Structure

Comment: @GrahamD i have changed the DeliveryBoy to drivers.

Comment: Please show how you populate the `onlineNearestDriversList` list and what it contains.

Comment: Hi  @GrahamD "onlineNearestDriversList" was used within the function for a for loop only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your responses and as far as I can see, you don't need the loop where you have it. Therefore, I am going to ignore it and simply show you the code that will return the list of driver ids of all `drivers` for `city` 'Lusaka'.

```
Future<List<String>> retrieveOnlineDriversInformation() async {
  final driverIds = <String>[];
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("drivers");
  try {
    await ref.orderByChild("city")
             .equalTo("Lusaka")
             .once()
             .then(
           (event) {
             if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
             final driverListData =
                 Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value! as Map);
             driverListData.forEach((key, value) {
                driverIds.add(key);
              });
             }
           },
  } on FirebaseException catch (error, stackTrace) {
  // < Some code here to print database error details or otherwise deal with it >
  } catch (error, stackTrace) {
  // < Some code here to print other error details or otherwise deal with it >
  }
  return driverIds;
}
```

You could instead modify this to just return the Map 'driverListData' which contains each driver's id and associated driver data.

A couple of other points:

You don't stick to a standard naming convention for your database node and field names. I suggest that you always use lowerCamelCase as the standard (so for example, change `DriverLicense` to `driverLicense`) as it will match what you typically name the variables within the Flutter/Dart code.

You don't need to hold the driver `id` as a separate field in the `driver` node. It is a duplicate (and therefore wastes space on the database) of the `driver` record key, which is already accessible to you.

As you see, you should always wrap your database call logic in a try / catch clauses in order to handle any errors that the call to the database may return. There are specific exceptions that can be tested for with the `on` clause.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise very hopeful never thought in those areas will definitely change.